# Annotation text above main text in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to get Chinese pinyin (Romanization) above Chinese characters in React Native.

I've *sorta* accomplished this - shown in the image below, with the following code:

```
{this.state.article.json.map((content, index) => (
  <Fragment>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{content.pinyin}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text
    >
      {content.simplified}
    </Text>

  </Fragment>
))}
```

However, none of the body text is inline. When I try to wrap this text with `<Text>` tags, it gets rid of the pinyin, or makes it inline as well, depending on the modification I make.

Is there anyway to get "above the text" annotations in React Native while maintaining the rest of the text being inline?

[image: Pinyin]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for my use case:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  {this.state.article.json.map((content, index) => (
    <View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{content.pinyin}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text
        >
          {content.simplified}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>

  ))}
</View>
```